# Significant difference between sample and population over time

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, z-test

I am comparing the daily number of stock depletions between multiple stores to identify stores with a significantly high number of depletions. 
I'm thinking that the appropriate method is a one-sided Z-test in which n= number of days for which observations are available, X= mean number of depletions per day for a given store (sample), and μ= mean number of depletions per day for all other stores (population). 
I will perform this test for each store and correct for multiple testing by dividing p= 0.05 by the number of stores. 
Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If different stores stock vastly different numbers of items and some are open weekends and some are not, I am not sure how to put stores in which you're inteested on the same scale of 'depletions' as the population.

Comment: Would it be valid to represent depletions as a percentage of items, and calculate the Z-score from the mean percentages?

Comment: What would be the denominator for the percentage? Items subject to going out of stock? Days in which an item can be out of stock? Some combination of items and days? Suppose a store has 1000 items and there are 25 business days in a month. Is the denom 1000? 25? 25,000? // I tried to propose an Answer, but found no way to make sense of it without more information or additional assumptions beyond the statement of your Question.. // Are all items equally likely to go out of stock? Are there relatively more depletions on weekends?

Comment: Are you trying to see if a particular store deviates significantly from average on any one _day_? Sorry but I don't see right now how a paired t test comes into this. Look at my "Answer." Not really an answer but too long for a comment. Maybe by criticizing it you can figure out what assumptions are realistic.

Comment: Yes, the denominator would be the number of products per store (1,000), and the numerator would be the number of products which are depleted on a given day. The number of days would be the sample size. I could use a paired sample T-test to control for seasonality (the weekday), or Wilcoxon signed-rank test if the distribution isn't normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See questions in my comment. Assume every item is equally likely to go out of stock on any one day. Suppose Item A out of stock for three days counts the same as Items A, E, and Q out of stock on Tuesday.

For each store in the population count item-days in both numerator and denominator of a fraction. If a store had 1000 items and was open for 25 days last month, then it had 25,000 item-days. Then maybe the store had 1750 item-days of depletions. (That could be all 1000 items out of stock on one day
and 750 out of stock on another day, or it could be  70 items out of stock on all 25 days.) Then its outage percentage was $p = 0.07.$

Do the same computation collectively for all stores in the population. Get numerator and denominator for the whole population. Maybe you get $p = 0.0682$ for the population last month.

Maybe a particular store of interest had 23,000 item-days last month, and
$x = 1518$ item-days of depletions. Is that significantly less than in the population? Assume item-days are indpendent (very unlikely).
If this store were typical of the population last month, it should have had
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=2300, p=0.0682)$ item days of depletions. Then $P(X \le 1518)=0.094 > 0.05,$ so at the 5% significance level this particular store was not doing significantly better than the population last month.

```
pbinom(1518, 23000, .0682)
[1] 0.09455519
```

Whenever I see binomial models with such large $n$ and relatively small $p,$ I wonder if there is a slightly different formulation of
the situation, using a Poisson distribution, that would be simpler.

Does it matter if the store is out of an item on a day when nobody
wanted that item? Maybe what you should count is the number of sales
lost in a month due to depletions. Modeling that count as Poisson might work.

Maybe a more direct approach would be to get the total revenue lost per
month due to depletions, and try to model that.

I am *not recommending* my formulation above, just illustrating how many
questionable assumptions I had to make in order to get a tractable
model.